# Styling Multi step Form

Tags: css

I am using a form page having multiple steps in it i want to design it something like this
[image]
<sub>(source: [fellowshipone.com](https://developer.fellowshipone.com/patterns/assets/images/screenshots/misc_step_wizard.gif))</sub>

the top part i.e. Step1, step2 etc.
how to achieve this using CSS

Comment: Do you want a CSS tutorial from scratch, or do you have a specific part you're not sure how to do in CSS?

Comment: actually iam not getting how to separate the steps using this ">"

Comment: If this is a website you are referencing in the image above, check the source html for their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be make a css sprite of all the possible step states, and make it one background image ( with or without the rounded corners ), set it on the div containing all the steps.. change it depending on the state ( specify a class ). float the steps which are `li`s and contain them on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTML structure:

```
<ul id="steps">
  <li class="visited"><a href="#"><span>Step 1</span><span>description</span></a></li>
  <li class="visited"><a href="#"><span>Step 2</span><span>description</span></a></li>
  <li class="current"><a href="#"><span>Step 3</span><span>description</span></a></li>
  <li class="upcoming"><a href="#"><span>Step 4</span><span>description</span></a></li>
  <li class="upcoming"><a href="#"><span>Step 5</span><span>description</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

You can then use css selectors li.visited, li.current, li.upcoming to select the li nodes and style them accordingly.

Comment: please tell me how to style it like the above especially the ">"